# Is a reference frame fixed (without rotation) on a precessing gyroscope an inertial frame of reference?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, rigid-body-dynamics, gyroscopes

Let's say we put a human in a closed chamber which is  going around a certain point at distance d from its center of mass at some angular velocity w.
The centrifugal force on a human will be w squared over r times his mass.
Is there any difference if the cause of this rotation is precession of a gyroscope connected to the chamber?[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. You seem to be mixing the effects of orbital motion with that of rotation. The short answer is that if the center of mass is _not_ moving in a straight line, there _must_ be a force that causes that. Can you elaborate a little more on the setup (maybe include a sketch) and describe the DOF that drive the kinematics of the system.

Comment: Doesnt matter what force. Of course there is a force. Do you not know what precession is?

Comment: In my mind precession is the slow rotation of the instantaneous rotation axis when it is not parallel to one of the principal rotation axes.

Comment: Yes. Slow relative to the rotation right? So doest really rave to be slow. I added a picture.

Comment: So if you fix a reference frame at the end of the gyroscope, and the frame is not itself rotating, only precessing, how many Gs of force will the person inside feel?

Comment: Thank you, now your question makes sense. Well, the question might be rephrased as where is the center of rotation of precession? Because once you have the radial distance $r$ and the precession speed $\omega$ you just calculate $a = -\omega^2 r$.

Comment: Yes it is. And thus the inertial centrifugal force in the frame should be m*a. But I am inclined to believe that for some reason that this is an inertial frame regardless of acceleration since there is no real centrifugal force..

Answer (score 1):

A reference frame rotating at the rate of a precessing gyroscope is still a rotating reference frame. It is not inertial. All of the usual effects in a rotating reference frame will be present including the usual centrifugal force.

Comment: I do not think so. There should be according to newstons laws. But I don't think there is

Comment: So which of Newton’s laws do you think is wrong in this case and exactly how do you think it fails?

Comment: No single one, Newtons laws don't work in all frames of reference all by them selves , to make the theory work you need to add some "inertial " forces. In this case there seems to be a contradiction with the Newtonian mechanics as you are in an accelerating frame and there at least in my opinion should be no inertial forces present.

Comment: There are inertial forces in this frame, specifically the centrifugal and the Coriolis forces.

Comment: Have you ever seen a gyroscope precessing on a toy Eiffel tower as a pivot?

Comment: Yes. Although it was not a toy Eiffel Tower, just a plastic base.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90821/discussion-between-dale-and-schaurberger).